# Corona SDK : How to identify the collision object?

Tags: lua, collision-detection, coronasdk

I'm a beginner in Corona developping and i've to problem to identify the collision between 3 objects. In fact, this is my code :

```
The first object is my player : 

player = display.newImageRect("ballon.png", 150,170 )
player.anchorX = 0.5
player.anchorY = 0.5
player.x = display.contentCenterX - 450
player.y = display.contentCenterY+250
physics.addBody(player, "static", {density=0.1, bounce=0.1, friction=0.1,})
player.myName="player"
screenGroup:insert(player)
```

The second object is created within a function :

```
function addWindSlow(self,event)

height = math.random(display.contentCenterY - 200, display.contentCenterY + 200)
windslow = display.newImage( "wind-neg.png")
windslow.x = display.contentWidth
windslow.y = height
windslow.speed = 4
windslow.myName="windslow"
physics.addBody(windslow, "static", {density = 0.1, bounce = 0, isSensor = false})
elements:insert(windslow) end

function addWindFast(self,event)

height = math.random(display.contentCenterY - 200, display.contentCenterY + 200)
windfast = display.newImage( "wind-pos.png")
windfast.x = display.contentWidth
windfast.y = height
windfast.speed = 4
windfast.myName="windfast"
physics.addBody(windfast, "static", {density = 0.1, bounce = 0, isSensor = false})
elements:insert(windfast) end
```

And finally, the thirth object is the same but called "addWindFast() with a different image"

So i would like to know once my player is on collision with the windslow, i need to do an action... and if it's the object windfast, another action.  That's my code :

```
function onCollision( event )


    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    if event.other.windslow and event.other.isVisible==true then
        print("windslow has been touch !")
    end

end
```

end

I found something about the pre-collision, I'll use it once i got the information how to "identify" the object...I'll need to prevent the collision and avoid it if the player is going to touch the windfast or windslow.

We thank you for all dude !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `windslow` and `windfast` are defined outside of `onCollision` event handler so you should compare to those:

```
function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        if event.other == windslow and event.other.isVisible==true then
            print("windslow has been touch !")
        end
        if event.other == windfast and event.other.isVisible==true then
            print("windfast has been touch !")
        end
    end
end -- (missing from your post but probably in your code)
```

The above assumes that you have registered for collision events on your player. You could also register a different collision handler on each wind:

```
windslow:addEventListener("collision", onCollisionSlow)
windfast:addEventListener("collision", onCollisionFast)
```

In that case the two collision handlers could just check `if event.other == player`. The advantage of that is you are separating the code for each one. You could of course do the same with your player handler:

```
function onCollisionSlow(other)
    print('collided with slow')
end

function onCollisionFast(other)
    print('collided with fast')
end

collisionHandlers = {
    [windslow] = onCollisionSlow, 
    [windfast] = onCollisionFast,
}

function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        collisionFunc = collisionHandlers[event.other]
        if collisionFunc ~= nil and event.other.isVisible then
            collisionFunc(event.other)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the other object with the myName property you've specified.

For example:

```
function onCollision( event )

   if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
      if (event.other.myName == "windslow" and event.other.isVisible==true) then
         print("windslow has been touched!")
      elseif (event.other.myName = "windfast" and event.other.isVisible==true) then
         print("windfast has been touched!")
   end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, in fact i used this :  function onCollision( event )

     if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
  
    if (event.object1.myName=="windslow" and 
     event.object2.myName =="player") then
      mydata.score = mydata.score + 1
      scoreText.text = mydata.score
      --elements[a].scoreAdded = true
      event.object1:removeSelf() (...) end

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked out. You should be careful with object1 and object2 though as I believe sometimes object1 could be player and object2 could be windslow, in which case you would miss the collision. If your problem is solved, feel free to vote up or 'accept' the best answer.

Comment: By the way ChubbRck : I tried your function, but I've an error "attempt to index field "other" (a nil value)... This is my function : ---- 
    if (event.other.myName == "windslow" and event.other.isVisible==true) then
             print("windslow has been touched!")
         end

Comment: Ah yes, are you adding the listener to Runtime or to the player? Try adding it to the player like so:
`player.collision = onCollision`  
`player:addEventListener( "collision", player )`